# Image go below the div and not alighed with it

Tags: css

**Hi,**

I am trying to code a design but I cannot get it aligned correctly no matter what I try it wont stay in the same place nicely.

Here is what it looks like

http://postimg.org/image/tuctjuglz/

Here is what it is meant to be like

http://postimg.org/image/4aajdev87/

and here is my code hopefully it can be fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>a</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/reset.css"/>
<style>
body {
color:#ffffff;
background:#1f1f1f url(style/images/background.png) repeat-x center top;
}

.profileMidSection {
height:239px;
width:860px;
color:#ffffff;
background:#2e2e2e;
clear:both;
}

ul.profileMidSection {
list-style:none;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:47px;
}

ul.profileMidSection li {
height:47px;
vertical-align:middle;
clear:both;
}

ul.profileMidSection li a{
height:47px;
width:175px;
background:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
color:#737373;
float:left;
text-align:left;
padding-left:25px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:600;
font-size:10.5pt;
margin-left:-40px;
}

ul.profileMidSection li a:hover{
color:#ffffff;
border-left:3px solid #83bdf2;
width:172px;
}

.profileCaption {
background:#3c3c3c;
width:200px;
height:35px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:600;
font-size:11pt;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="profileMidSection">

        <ul class="profileMidSection">
            <li><a href="#">Recommended Games</a></li>
            <li style="margin-top:1px;"><a href="#">Your Friends Played</a></li>
            <li style="margin-top:1px;"><a href="#">You Liked</a></li>
            <li style="margin-top:1px;"><a href="#">Your Friends Liked</a></li>
            <li style="margin-top:1px;"><a href="#">Disliked</a></li>
        </ul>

          <img src="games/images/caption1.png" />
          <div class="profileCaption">Angry Birds&trade;</div>
          <img src="games/images/caption2.png" />
          <div class="profileCaption">Mario Kart Pro&trade;</div>    
          <img src="games/images/caption3.png" />
          <div class="profileCaption">Lazy&trade;</div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each image and caption in a `div` with a class like `game-thumb` and float the class left. Then, enclose all games in another `div` container, and set `overflow:hidden` on it.

Comment: Thanks that got me 1 step closer now it is just the all the images are aligned together on one line and the menu you bar on the line above.

Comment: Float the menu to the left and add a margin-left to the game gallery that offsets the menu's width.